# The LED light in one fixture gets BRIGHTER when I turn on the LED light in another fixture

Tags: electrical, lighting, circuit

I have a very old house with unknown wiring, two ceiling light fixtures in the living room, and a very strange problem with the lighting in these fixtures:

When I turn on the first LED ceiling light via its pull-chain switch it works as expected. But when I turn on the other LED ceiling light via its wall switch, the second light turns on as expected -- but at the same time the first light gets BRIGHTER.

If anything, I would expect that turning on the second light would cause the first light to get dimmer (due to the added resistance) but this seems to be incorrect. Can anyone tell me what might be going on here?

Comment: Does one light have to be on for the other to turn on?

Comment: Does the "second light" in your question act the same way if you turn on "the second" first, and the first, second? *i.e.* if you switch the order of turning them on, is the behavior the same (that the light first turned on gets brighter when the next light is turned on?) So, Wall switch, then Pull chan, what happens?

Comment: Yes, when I turn on the light controlled by the wall switch it turns on somewhat dimly, then when I turn on the pull-chain light it lights -- and the wall switch light gets brighter.

Comment: So basically whichever light I switch on first will light, but it only lights dimly -- until I turn on the other light -- then they both seem to get "full power" and are brightly lit. I also noticed that when I turn one light off (and it doesn't matter which one) the other gets dim. It's almost as if neither light is getting "full power" unless they are both switched on.

Comment: Are you using screw in LED bulbs or are there actual LED fixtures using drivers to power the LEDs?

Comment: Both LED lights are screw-in type. They are the kind with 3 or 4 "wings" that fold up and down to direct the light around the room. I simply screwed them into the existing old-style porcelain socket-type fixtures.

Comment: Turn off the power at the breaker, double check power is off.  Undo the the fixtures and switch and check for loose connections.  Take pictures of fixtures and switch with wires showing and post them.

Comment: is the wall switch a plain switch or something fancy like a timer/motion/photoeye/dimmer? If it's fancy, you might not be drawing enough current to turn/hold the SCR/triac fully on; they were meant for high-draw resistive loads (incandescent bulbs).

Comment: Correction: My wife gave me more information. It seems there is a second wall switch connected to the wall switch light that I did not know about. The "wall switch light" is therefore on a 3-way circuit so I will call this light the "3-way light".

When the pull-chain light is off and either 3-way switch is on, the 3-way light is dimly lit. But when the pull-chain light is switched on, the 3-way light get brighter and the pull-chain light gets dimmer. Previously I thought they both got brighter at the same time but this is not the case.

Comment: Another way to describe this situation is as follows: apparently, turning on the 3-way light draws some power from the pull-chain light.

It's a 100 year old house with no special or fancy timers/switches/dimmers/etc. Just really old wiring, simple old switches, and old light sockets. 

I wish I knew how to draw a wiring diagram that would illustrate how a loose connection might create such a situation, because if a loose connection is not the cause then perhaps the house was wired incorrectly from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry crip659, I cannot perform your suggested actions at this time.